# Is a while loop with a nested for loop O(n) or O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, while-loop, big-o, complexity-theory

I have 2 blocks of code. One with a single while loop, and the second with a for loop inside the while loop.  My professor is telling me that Option 1 has an algorithm complexity of O(n) and Option 2 has an algorithm complexity of O(n^2), however can't explain why that is, other than pointing to the nested for loops.  I am confused because both perform the exact same number of calculations for any given size N, which doesn't seem to be indicative that they have different algorithm complexities.

I'd like to know:

a) if my professor is correct, and how they can boast the same calculations but have different big Os.

b) if my professor is incorrect and they are the same complexity, is it O(n) or O(n^2)?  Why?

---

I've used inline comments denoted by '#' to note the computations.  Packages to deliver should be N.  Self.trucks is a list.  self.isWorkDayComplete is a boolean determined by whether all packages have been delivered.

Option 1:

```
# initializes index for fake for loop
truck_index = 0   
while(not self.workDayCompleted):
    # checks if truck index has reached end of self.trucks list
    if(truck_index != len(self.trucks)): 
        # does X amount of calculations required for delivery of truck's packages
        while(not self.trucks[truck_index].isEmpty()):
            trucks[truck_index].travel()
            trucks[truck_index].deliverPackage() 
        if(hub.packagesExist()):
            truck[truck_index].travelToHub()
            truck[truck_index].loadPackages()
        # increments index
        truck_index += 1 
    else:
        # resets index to 0 for next iteration set through truck list
        truck_index = 0 
        # does X amount of calculations required for while loop condition
        self.workDayCompleted = isWorkDayCompleted()
```

Option 2:

```
while(not self.workDayCompleted):
    # initializes index (i)
    # each iteration checks if truck index has reached end of self.trucks list
    # increments index
    for i in range(len(trucks)):   
        # does X amount of calculations required for Delivery of truck's packages
        while(not self.trucks[i].isEmpty()):
            trucks[i].travel()
            trucks[i].deliverPackage()
        if(hub.packagesExist()):
            truck[i].travelToHub()
            truck[i].loadPackages()  
    # does X amount of calculations required for while loop condition
    self.workDayCompleted = isWorkDayCompleted()
```

### **Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!**

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow with no knowledge of the data structures.

Comment: self.trucks is a list, and self.workDayCompleted is a boolean.  I'm specifically interested in the algorithm complexity based on the coding logic shown, regardless of the number of calculations or data structures used.  Essentially Option 1 is a while loop with a self-constructed for loop that does all the same things Option 2 does, but using the while loop's iterations.  Whenever Option 1 or 2 is ran, both will run "Do work for truck" the same number of times.

Comment: Better to post the true code than pseudo code.

Comment: Updated to use real code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly seems like these two pieces of code are effectively implementing the same algorithm (i.e. deliver a package with each truck, then check to see if the work day is completed, repeat until the work day is completed).  From this perspective you're right to be skeptical.

The question becomes: are they O(n) or O(n<sup>2</sup>)?  As you've described it, this is impossible to determine because we don't know what the conditions are for the work day being completed.  Is it related to the amount of work that has been done by the trucks?  Without that information we have no ability to reason about when the outer loop exits.  For all we know the condition is that each truck must deliver 2<sup>n</sup> packages and the complexity is actually O(n 2<sup>n</sup>).

So if your professor is right, my only guess is that there's a difference between the implementations of `isWorkDayCompleted()` between the two options.  Barring something like that, though, the two options should have the same complexity.

Regardless, when it comes to problems like this it is always important to make sure that you're both talking about the same things:

1. What `n` means (presumably the number of trucks)
2. What you're counting (presumably the number of deliveries and maybe also the checks for the work day being done)
3. What the end state is (this is the red flag for me -- the work day being completed needs better defined)

---

Subsequent edits lead me to believe both of these options are O(n), since they ultimately perform one or two "travel" operations per package, depending on the number of trucks and their capacity.  Given this, I think the answer to your core question (do those different control structures result in different complexity analysis) is no, they don't.

It also seems unlikely that the internals are affecting the code complexity in some important way, so my advice would be to get back together with your professor and see if they can expand on their thoughts.  It very well might be that this was an oversight on their part or that they were trying to make a more subtle point about how some of the component you're using were implemented.

If you get their explanation and there is something more complex going on that you still have trouble understanding, that should probably be a separate question (perhaps linked to this one).

Comment: Thanks a ton!  This is super helpful.  
N should be the packages to deliver.  I've specified further what the "work" is that the trucks do in the code by including another layer of my coding to the example - a while loop that has the truck travel and deliver all the packages.
The "end state", or work day being completed is when all packages have been delivered.  It is determined when there are no packages in either truck, and no packages left at the hub.

Comment: @TheEggSample Other questions: Is the number of trucks a fixed number independent of the number of packages?  How many packages can each carry?  That said, given that all the trucks are traveling one at a time (instead of working in parallel) those answer probably don't matter.

Also, the expanded code makes me re-question: what is being counted? If you're counting any amount of traveling by the trucks as 1 unit of time, these still seem equivalent, and since there's one traveling period per package (plus the occasional trip back to the hub), that still seems like O(n) for both algorithms.

Comment: I have it set up so when I create the hub object, I can choose how many trucks it has.  It is a fixed number that does not change after the hub is created.  When I set up those fixed trucks, I set a fixed capacity for each truck.  The goal of the whole program is to deliver packages in the shortest mileage, keeping track of delivery times and package delivery deadlines.  Even though I'm not running each truck in parallel, they retain an internal clock.  That clock affects how and what packages they can pick up in conjunction with the other truck's clocks.

Comment: The units of time are determined by truck speed (mph) and distance (miles) from delivery location.

Comment: @TheEggSample Interesting, could be something odd happening internal to the trucks, but it seems more like your professor may not have looked too closely at this.  I appreciate the desire to get more to the heart of what's happening but my feeling as it stands is that your question was, very reasonably, about whether the two control structure-variants (while loop with counter and if-statement vs while loop with for loop) have different code complexity.  The additional edits are moving further and further away from a minimal example though...  I'll edit my answer with some final thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

> a) if my professor is correct, and how they can boast the same calculations but have different big Os.

Two algorithms that do the same number of "basic operations" have the same time complexity, regardless how the code is structured.

> b) if my professor is incorrect and they are the same complexity, is it O(n) or O(n^2)? Why?

First you have to define: what is "n"? Is n the number of trucks? Next, does the number of "basic operations" per truck the same or does it vary in some way?

For example: If the number of operations per truck is constant C, the total number of operations is C*n. That's in the complexity class O(n).